# NEXT APP Router Error: POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/register 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, mongoose-schema, next-auth

I am trying to register users using email and password with next auth, mongodb and mongoose. But whenever the form is completed I receive this error "POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/register 500 (Internal Server Error)".
I am currently making use of the next app router for page routing.
Here's my code

Register Form Component

```
type here
"use client";

import styles from "@/app/styles/register/Form.module.css";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useState } from "react";

const Form = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    name: "",
  });
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<null | string>(null);

  const handleChange = (
    event:
      | React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
      | React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>,
  ) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setForm((prevFormData) => {
      return {
        ...prevFormData,
        [name]: value,
      };
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, email, password } = form;

    try {
      const res = await fetch("/api/auth/register", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name,
          email,
          password,
        }),
      });
      res.status === 201 &&
        router.push("/login?success=Account has been created");
    } catch (err: any) {
      setMessage(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      autoComplete="off"
      className={`${styles.form_container} mt-10 flex justify-center items-center flex-col`}
    >
      <fieldset className="w-full mx-4 flex justify-center items-center flex-col">
        <div className="w-full px-2">
          <label
            htmlFor="name"
            className="text-sm"
          >
            Full Name
          </label>
          <input
            name="name"
            id="name"
            type="text"
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            autoComplete="false"
            value={form.name}
            className="p-3 w-full border-solid border-[1px] border-[#EAECEF]"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="w-full px-2">
          <label
            htmlFor="email"
            className="text-sm"
          >
            Email
          </label>
          <input
            name="email"
            id="email"
            type="email"
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
            autoComplete="off"
            value={form.email}
            className="p-3 w-full border-solid border-[1px] border-[#EAECEF]"
          />
        </div>

        <div className="w-full px-2">
          <label
            htmlFor="password"
            className="text-sm"
          >
            Password
          </label>
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            required
            autoComplete="new-password"
            id="password"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={form.password}
            className="p-3 w-full border-solid border-[1px] border-[#EAECEF]"
          />
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <div className="flex flex-col w-full items-center px-2">
        <p className="w-full text-left">
          <Link
            href="/login"
            className="text-lightColor hover:text-primaryColor hover:underline"
          >
            {" "}
            Login with an existing account
          </Link>
        </p>
        {message && <p className="text-red-700 my-2 text-xl">{message}</p>}
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="text-center my-12 flex-1 w-full bg-[#2c6e49] hover:bg-lightColor hover:font-semibold rounded-md p-[1rem] px-4 mx-2  text-white cursor-pointer"
        >
          Register
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Register Page

```
import { Metadata } from "next";

import Form from "./Form";
import { poppins } from "../lib/utils/font";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Gamer Swap | Register",
};

const Register = () => {
  return (
    <main className="mt-28">
      <section className="mx-auto max-w-sm">
        <h2
          className={`leading-[1.15] text-xl sm:text-2xl font-semibold font-sans px-2 ${poppins.variable}`}
        >
          Create Personal Account
        </h2>
        <Form />
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

next auth
/api/auth/register/route.ts

```
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import User from "@/app/lib/models/User";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import dbConnect from "@/app/lib/utils/dbConnect";

export const POST = async (request: {
  json: () =>
    | PromiseLike<{ name: any; email: any; password: any }>
    | { name: any; email: any; password: any };
}) => {
  const { name, email, password } = await request.json();

  await dbConnect();

  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 5);

  const newUser = new User({
    name,
    email,
    password: hashedPassword,
  });

  try {
    await newUser.save();
    return new NextResponse("User has been created", {
      status: 201,
    });
  } catch (err: any) {
    return new NextResponse(err.message, {
      status: 500,
    });
  }
};
```

User Model

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);

// UserSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
//   if (!this.isModified("password")) {
//     const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
//     this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
//   }
//   next();
// });

// UserSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (password: string) {
//   return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
// };

export default mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

auth options

```
import type { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";
import User from "../models/User";
import dbConnect from "./dbConnect";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      id: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "email@example.com",
        },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        await dbConnect();
        // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
        if (credentials == null) return null;
        // login

        try {
          const user = await User.findOne({ email: credentials.email });

          if (user) {
            const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(
              credentials.password,
              user.password,
            );
            if (isMatch) {
              return user;
            } else {
              throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
            }
          } else {
            throw new Error("User not found");
          }
        } catch (err: any) {
          throw new Error(err);
        }
      },
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET!,
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET!,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
    newUser: "/register",
    error: "/login",
  },
  callbacks: {
    // We can pass in additional information from the user document MongoDB returns
    async jwt({ token, user }: any) {
      if (user) {
        token.user = {
          _id: user._id,
          email: user.email,
          password: user.name,
        };
      }
      return token;
    },
    // If we want to access our extra user info from sessions we have to pass it the token here to get them in sync:
    session: async ({ session, token }: any) => {
      if (token) {
        session.user = token.user;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
};
```

Mongoose Connection

```
declare global {
  var mongoose: any; // This must be a `var` and not a `let / const`
}

const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI!;

if (!MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error(
    "Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local",
  );
}

let cached = global.mongoose;

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null };
}

async function dbConnect() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn;
  }
  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      bufferCommands: false,
    };
    cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then((mongoose) => {
      return mongoose;
    });
  }
  try {
    cached.conn = await cached.promise;
  } catch (e) {
    cached.promise = null;
    throw e;
  }

  return cached.conn;
}

export default dbConnect;
```

The expected behaviour is for the user to be registered and the password encrypted with bcrypt while these details are submitted to the database. The page should also redirect to the login page on success.

Comment: What error are you getting on the server?